# SharePoint 2016 Custom List: Accordion with jQuery Icons

Tags: jquery, 2016, css, sharepoint-server, icons

I have used the code below for my SharePoint Custom FAQ List, and it works pretty fine. Now I would like to add jQuery UI icons such as ui-icon-plus (+) and ui-icon-minus (-) icons.

How do I do that? I am new to jQuery.

Thanks. Cheers.

```
(function () {

    var overrideCurrentContext = {};
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates = {};

    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='ListAccordion'>";
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

    overrideCurrentContext.OnPostRender = OnPostRender;
    overrideCurrentContext.Templates.Item = ItemTemplate;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCurrentContext);

})();



function ItemTemplate(ctx) {
    var Question  = ctx.CurrentItem["Question"];
    var Answer = ctx.CurrentItem["Answer"];

    return "<h2>" + Question + "</h2><p>" + Answer + "</p><br/>";
    }

function OnPostRender() {

    $('.ListAccordion h2').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).next().hide();

    $('.ListAccordion h2').css({
    "background-color": "grey", 
    "cursor": "pointer", 
    "color": "white" ,
    "border-radius" : "15px",
    "padding-left" : "10px"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below bootstrap and font awesome example, which is used for the SharePoint dynamic accordion with + and -

**Jquery and html code**

```
html]<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
var inEditMode = Utils.checkPageInEditMode();
// Prevent the collapsing of <h2> blocks when in SharePoint's [Edit Mode]
if (!inEditMode) {
UI.collapseContentHeaders();
UI.toggleContentHeaders();
}
});

var UI = {
collapseContentHeaders: function () {
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2').each(function (index, value) {
// Collapses all <h2> blocks except for the first encountered
if (index > 0) {
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(100);
}
});
},
toggleContentHeaders: function () {
// Toggles the accordion behavior for <h2> regions onClick
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2').click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('h2').slideToggle(100);
});
}
}

var Utils = {
checkPageInEditMode: function () {
var pageEditMode = null;
var wikiPageEditMode = null;

// Edit check for Wiki Pages
if (document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode) {
wikiPageEditMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName]._wikiPageMode.value;
}
// Edit check for all other pages
if (document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode) {
pageEditMode = document.forms[MSOWebPartPageFormName].MSOLayout_InDesignMode.value;
}
// Return the either/or if one of the page types is flagged as in Edit Mode
if (!pageEditMode && !wikiPageEditMode) {
return false;
}
return pageEditMode == "1" || wikiPageEditMode == "Edit";
}
}
</script>[/html]
```

**Styling the Headings with CSS**

```
    html]
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
/*** CSS for collasable headers ***/
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2 {
background: #0072C6;
padding: .25em;
border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}
/*** Collapsed h2 ***/
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2.expand:before {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f0fe ';
}
/*** Expanded h2 ***/
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain h2:before {
font-family: 'FontAwesome';
content: '\f146 ';
}
</style>
[/html]
```

**Demo Example:**

[image: SharePoint_dynamic_accordions_example]

Reference URL :

[How to Create Dynamic Accordions in SharePoint Pages](https://www.google.com/amp/s/info.summit7systems.com/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-accordions-in-sharepoint-pages%3Fhs_amp=true)